# How to fix image sharing to locked application error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to make "share image" button to my android application. But when I try share image to locked application, I got "Error" toast message after entering the password. When I share to unlocked application, it works perfectly. It's not Android OS bug, because sharing from gallery to locked applications works fine.

I used this code to share image file:

```
val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
share.type = "image/*"

val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, file)
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"))
```

Toast error message
[image]

Comment: what error do you get? Can you describe us?

Comment: @TehMattGR There is no any errors displayed in the console. I only have a toast message with this text: "Error"